# CSS and HTML centering an <h1> next to an <img>

Tags: html, css

Right now I have...

```
<header id="background-color">
    <img src="header_image.gif" alt="header">   
    <h1>Header</h1>
</header>
```

and the relevant CSS is...

```
header {
    background: #0072bc;
    width: 70%;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
    text-align: center;
}
#background-color {
    background: #0066CC;
    width: 100%;
}
```

This puts the image above the h1 obviously.  What I'd like to do is left-justify the image and have the h1 centered relative to the whole page (not just the remaining space).

And when I say left-justify, I mean relative to the body and header which are set to be 70% with auto margins.  I've got no idea how to do this, I'm totally new to web design.

Thanks.

Comment: do you mean that the image and header should go side by side where image should be on the left of the header and header at the center of the page?

Comment: try this http://jsfiddle.net/a7Jnz/

Comment: @I_Debug_Everything That did put them next to each other, but the image is bigger than the header.  It goes outside the blue area I have for the header.  Is there a way to make the blue area taller?

Comment: @I_Debug_Everything It also didn't center the <h1> relative to the page, it centered it based on the remaining space after the image

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can add `margin-right: -100%;` to image, so header text will not touch the right edge of image. and will align center in header. [check this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/a7Jnz/2/)

Answer (score 0):

```
header {
background-color: #0072bc;
width: 70%;
text-align: left;
padding: 10px;
}
```

Look at the jsfiddle

http://jsfiddle.net/EScBs/

Comment: No I'm not, just trying to put them next to each other on the top of my page

Comment: obviously you may need your own image and code but they are aligned at the top of the page next to each other. If I didn't understand the question correctly I am sorry

Comment: Thanks for the response.  This http://jsfiddle.net/a7Jnz/ is what I'm looking for, but I want the <h1> to be centered in the whole page.  If you look, its not centered relative to the whole page, its centered in the remaining space between the image and the rest of the page

Answer (score 0):

A quick Answer.. May need to fine tune...

Add wrapping div...

```
<header id="background-color">
    <div id="container">
        <img src="Beach_Party.jpg" alt="header">   
        <h1>Header</h1>
    </div>
</header>
```

Try to use relative positioning and absolute positioning of the child elements

```
<style>
    header {
        background: #0072bc;
        width: 70%;
        margin-left: auto;
        margin-right: auto;
        text-align: center;
    }
    #background-color {
        background: #0066CC;
        width: 100%;
    }
    img {
        float:left;
        text-align:left;
        position: absolute;
        top:0;
        left:0;
    }
    h1 {
        z-index:10;
    }
    #container {
        position: relative;
    }
</style>
```

It worked for me.. Adjust it to suit your case.. Hope it helps!